# Multi-dimension input array checking in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-form-helper

Currently I have data that it must has 1 title and 1 content, and randomly number (or none) link group (linktext and link ) , (as the it is dynamic generated) E.g. LinkText1 , Link1 , LinkText2, Link2....and so on. So, one example data is:

```
title:"abc"
content:"test"
linktext1:"yahoo"
link1:"http://yahoo.com"
```

my form is

```
<input type="text" name="linktext[]">
<input type="text" name="link[]">
```

The problem is, 
simply

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('linkTxt[]', '連結標題', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('link[]', '連結地址', 'required');
```

is not working

I would like to if either linkTxt[0] or link[0] (or any pair) is exist , check the corresponding pair. If none of them exist (User can choose not to insert any link) (then no checking require) Thanks

Comment: what is your error? what does your input look like? Can you var_dump(linkTxt) and do you see data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(set_value('linkTxt') or set_value('link') ){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('linkTxt[]', '連結標題', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('link[]', '連結地址', 'required');
}
```

Basically, Set_value('input_field') will return false if no value . 
(I'm not 100% sure if this works with array inputs, otherwise try

```
$this->input->post('linkTxt[]')
```

If stil don't work, Might stick into a forloop and test each linkTxt for a value.